# CSS Transition item in and out of flexbox smooth animation

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm building basic navigation for a website, and the graphical/animated functionality that I would like is this:

1: When in the 'HOME' state, the site logo/icon is large and centered and above the rest of the navigation/page links.

2: When on any other page than home, the logo/icon is smaller, and sits proportionally in a horizontal flexbox with the other elements.

3: There is a smooth transition between these two states.

I've implemented this already as you can see below, but the transition is jittery when page is full sized. I am new to both CSS and Angular, so forgive my ignorance in advance.

My question:

Is there a better way to implement a into/out-of flexbox animation than i've provided here, and/or is there a CSS animation optimization that I am missing to smooth this transition further?

The end product will all have a similar background color, but I have chosen bright colors in this illustration to show what the divs are doing in the background.

Note: I've tried using 'will-change' to no real effect, and I'm aware that I can do this without using angular, but there are features beyond this simple animation that will utilize angular down the road.

Here is a fiddle for it too:
https://jsfiddle.net/willcthomson/f6wk4Lpq/

```js
/* angular */ 
function mainCtrl($scope) { 

    $scope.ng_div_home = 'div_home_scale_up';
      $scope.ng_div_logo = 'div_logo_scale_up';
      $scope.ng_div_logo_upper_container = 'div_logo_upper_container_scale_up';
      $scope.ng_logo = '';
      $scope.ng_ISHOME = true;

    $scope.f_scale = function()
      {
            if(!$scope.ng_ISHOME)
              {
              $scope.ng_div_home = "div_home_scale_down";
              $scope.ng_div_logo = "div_logo_scale_down";
              $scope.ng_div_logo_upper_container = 'div_logo_upper_container_scale_down';
              }
            else
              {
              $scope.ng_div_home = "div_home_scale_up";
              $scope.ng_div_logo = "div_logo_scale_up";
              $scope.ng_div_logo_upper_container = 'div_logo_upper_container_scale_up';
              }
            console.log("ishome is:"+$scope.ng_ISHOME);
      };


}
```

```css
/* css */
html{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #222222;
  }

body{
  background-color: #00000000;
  }


/*a container that sits on top of the nav bar and grows vertically to make room fo the expanding logo-icon*/
.div_logo_upper_container 
  {
    /* background-color: #111111; */
    background-color: magenta;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    transition: height .5s linear;
    margin-top: 5vw;
  }

/*a flex container to hold nav elements*/
.nav_container 
  {
    /* background-color: #111111; */
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 80%;
    
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;    
    
    align-items: stretch;
    align-items: flex-end;
 
  }
  

/*a div that scales forcing the other flex elements respond */
.div_home
    {
      background-color: #00000000;
      background-color: cyan;
      margin: auto;
      transition: .5s linear;
      will-change: transform, width, flex,;
    }

/*a div that holds the logo, and does the actual scaling and movement*/
.div_logo    
    {
      padding: 3px;
      margin: 3px;
      margin-left: 2vw;
      transition:  .5s linear;
      will-change: width;
    }

.img_logo   
    {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 8%;
    min-height: 8%;
    will-change:width;
    will-change:height;
    }

/*expands the home container amongst the other flex elements to make room for incoming logo*/
.div_home_scale_down
  {
    width: 10vw;
    flex: .5 1 40px;
  }    

/*shrinks the home container to allow flex elements to expand into the created gap*/
.div_home_scale_up
  {
    width: 3px;
    transform: translate(25vw,-10vh);
    align-self: center;
  }    

/*expands the logo container*/
.div_logo_scale_up
  {
    width: 30vw;
    margin-top: 5vh;
  }

/*shrinks the logo container*/
.div_logo_scale_down
  {
    margin: 1vh;
    width: 10vw;  
    position: static;

  }

/*expands the area above the nav container to contain the larger icon*/
.div_logo_upper_container_scale_up
  {
    height: 10vh;
  }  

/*shrinks the upper container as the icon files in with other elements  */
.div_logo_upper_container_scale_down
  {
    height: 1px;
  }  

.nav_items
    {
    flex: 1 1 10px;
    margin-bottom: 2vh;

    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 30px;
    color:grey;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 3px;
    transition: font-size, color, transform, .5s linear;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--html-->
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">

<div class="div_logo_upper_container" ng_class="ng_div_logo_upper_container"></div>
<div class="nav_container">
    <div class = "div_home" ng-class="ng_div_home">
      <div class = "div_logo" ng-class="ng_div_logo" ng-click="ng_ISHOME=true;f_scale();">
        <img  class = "img_logo" src="https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/579414?s=200&v=4" > 
      </div>
    </div>
   <div  class = "nav_items">   
    <p ng-click="ng_ISHOME=false;f_scale();">Two</p>
   </div>
   <div class = "nav_items">
    <p ng-click="ng_ISHOME=false;f_scale();">Three</p>
   </div>
   <div class = "nav_items">
    <p ng-click="ng_ISHOME=false;f_scale();">Four</p>
   </div>
    
  </div> <!-- end nav_container -->
  </div> <!-- end ctrl -->
  </div> <!-- end app -->
```

asdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is "jittery" because you are animating too many properties at once and they affect more than Paint and Composite layers.

If you find the above statement vague, please refer to these two articles:

- [Rendering Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/) from Google
- [High Performance Animations](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/).

The generally accepted solution for this type of animations is to have one element in DOM for each of the two animation states. They should both be positioned (any `position` value other than `static` will do). You'll use `transform` to animate the starting state element towards the position and size of the target state element. By getting [.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on each, you can determine the required transforms needed to make the exact transition).

By far, the biggest advantage of this method is that the element being animated remains at the same position in document flow and, by not being resized or moved, it doesn't trigger reflow on subsequent DOM elements or parents. Only its rendered projection is moved.

Once the animation ends, you toggle both elements's `visibility` and remove the `transform`s from the one you just animated (now hidden - you want to set `animation-duration:0s;` for this change), in order to reset the rendered projection back to its normal place in DOM.

Comment: Thanks Andrei! I think I understand the approach you've lined out to help me smoothly animate the icon between two states, but the additional behavior I'm looking for, has (1: the other items in the flexbox, 2: the size of the containing area 3: the content below the container) all responding to the animation. I've enjoyed stubbornly trying to make this work, but am I asking too much from the browser? Should I just back off and simplify the behavior? or do you have any other optimizations I might focus on to try and smooth this out? I've got lot's to learn yet, thanks for the resources too.

Comment: @Will, animations done with `transition` and `opacity` are very "light", because none of them requires recalculating any other element except the one being animated. Whereas methods which trigger changes in layout mean every single element after the one being animated is recalculated on each frame. It might not seem so, but the difference in computation is **huge**. As long as you stick to first method, there are no limits to the number of elements you can animate at one time.